# UIPickerView selecting row in wrong component (exorcism required?)

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I don't know what I've done to anger the gods but my UIPickerView is behaving abnormally. It has 2 components, for month and year values, and selecting a value on the right component (year) causes the left component (month) to change value as well.

I initially create the UIPickerView using the following code:

```
pickerView = UIPickerView(frame: ...)
pickerView.delegate = self
pickerView.dataSource = self
```

Then I implement some simple delegate / data source methods to handle the picker view, as follows:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if component == 0 {
        expirationMonth = months[row]
    } else {
        expirationYear = years[row]
    }
    expirationTextField?.text = "\(expirationMonth ?? "")/\(expirationYear?.substring(from: 2) ?? "")"
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if component == 0 {
        return months[row]
    } else {
        return years[row]
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if component == 0 {
        return months.count
    } else {
        return years.count
    }
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 2
}
```

Additionally, the UIPickerView data source method `numberOfComponents` is being called even when I don't set the picker view's data source.

I have no idea what's causing this behavior. I've tried pretty much everything and nothing is stopping it from changing both column's values. Does anyone have any ideas to fix this?

Comment: Do you have a `didSet` on either your `expirationMonth` or `expirationYear` iVars?

Comment: @DuncanC No, they are only changed by the methods seen above.

Comment: @DuncanC Turned out to be an iOS simulator bug.

Answer (score 5):

Turns out it's a bug in the iOS simulator, because when running it on my iPhone it worked like a charm. I thought I was going crazy there for a second!

I'm going to file a bug complaint in the morning...Good luck to anyone else with this issue.

Comment: I can confirm that I experience the same problem in the simulator, but not on my phone.

Comment: i have the same issue too on simulator, works fine on real device